# How to upgrade existing Micronaut application to new Micronaut version 1.1.2?

Tags: gradle, micronaut

I have been upgrading like this..

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.2"
}

apply plugin:"application"
apply plugin:"groovy"

version "0.1"
group "com.shanky"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.1.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime-groovy"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-views'
    runtime 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.11.RELEASE'
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm"
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-security"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-security"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-security-session"
    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.9.Final"
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1')

mainClassName = "com.shanky.Application"

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs.add('-Dgroovy.parameters=true')
}
```

So far this is my build.gradle file. I have updated mavenBom to upgrade Micronaut version. I've create a dummy project with Micronaut version 1.1.2 just to differentiate build.gradle file. I don't see any major difference in between them.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> But it is not upgrading.

That is unlikely to be correct.  It may be that you aren't seeing the effect of that change in your IDE if the IDE is out of sync with your Gradle build but changing that version number in `build.gradle` does in fact upgrade the project.

Comment: I changed the version number from 0.1 to 1.1.2, still I don't seen any result

Comment: "I changed the version number from 0.1 to 1.1.2, still I don't seen any result" - That doesn't make any sense to me.  The bom is where we get the version numbers from.  Best of luck.

Comment: In order for that to be true, your build must have some unusual items in it that you didn't mention in your question.

Comment: I have edited my post with my full build.gradle file change.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are describing and in order for the behavior you are describing to manifest, I think that would require a bug in Gradle.  If you can reproduce it in a share-able app, you should report a bug to them and show them your sample.